# Enum (flags) member composed of other members

Tags: f#

```
[<Flags>]
type LikeMatch =
    | None  = 0
    | Start = 1
    | End   = 2
    | All   = Start ||| End //ERROR: Unexpected identifier in union case
```

I've also tried qualifying the members with the enum type. Is there a way to do this in F#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the F# language reference there is no way to do this.  The right hand side of the = sign in a F# enum must be an integer literal

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233216(v=VS.100).aspx

Grammar

```
type enum-name =
   | value1 = integer-literal1
   | value2 = integer-literal2
```

Answer (score 29):

As JaredPar says it's not allowed by the language, but F# does have binary literals which makes it easy to show which bits are being set:

```
open System

[<Flags>]
type LikeMatch =
    | None  = 0b000000000
    | Start = 0b000000001
    | End   = 0b000000010
    | All   = 0b000000011
```

Answer (score 1):

We can define flag combinations:

1. Inline - see [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867080/8634147)
2. In a companion module

Each option has its pros and cons.

#### 1. Inline combinations by hand

```ml
[<System.Flags>]
type LikeMatch =
    | None  = 0b00
    | Start = 0b01
    | End   = 0b10
    | All   = 0b11 // ❌ Not human-friendly (more difficult to understand it's "Start + End")

let all = LikeMatch.All
// val all: LikeMatch = All

let all' = LikeMatch.Start ||| LikeMatch.End
// val all': LikeMatch = All
// ✔️ Compiler-friendly
```

#### 2. In a companion module

```ml
[<System.Flags>]
type Spacing =
    | Left   = 0b0001
    | Right  = 0b0010
    | Top    = 0b0100
    | Bottom = 0b1000

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Spacing =
    let Horizontal = Spacing.Left ||| Spacing.Right  // ✔️ Human-friendly
    let Vertical = Spacing.Top ||| Spacing.Bottom
    let All = Horizontal ||| Vertical

let horizontal = Spacing.Horizontal
// val horizontal: Spacing = Left, Right
// ❌ Not "Horizontal"
```

There's also a difference regarding `HasFlag`, whether combinations are included or not:

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Enum =
    let values<'enum when 'enum :> System.Enum> =
        System.Enum.GetValues(typeof<'enum>)
        :?> 'enum array
        |> Array.toList

    let flags<'enum when 'enum :> System.Enum> (enumValue: 'enum) =
        values<'enum>
        |> List.filter (enumValue.HasFlag)

let flagsInline = Enum.flags LikeMatch.All
// val flagsInline: LikeMatch list = [None; Start; End; All]
// ⚠️ Includes "None" and "All"

let flagsCompanion = Enum.flags Spacing.All
// val flagsCompanion: Spacing list = [Left; Right; Top; Bottom]
//  Only includes core flags
```